# How to call inner function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning jQuery and saw this chunk of code.

myJqueryFile.js

```
(function($, undefined) {

    function Calendar(element, options, eventSources) {
        var t = this;
        t.incrementDate = incrementDate;

        ....some code here

        function incrementDate(years) {
            if (years !== undefined) {
                addYears(date, years);
            }

            renderView();
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

In my html, I am referencing the js above externally and want to call incrementDate() but I'm keep getting "increment is not function".

But I think incrementDate() is not private function so I should be able to call it from outside. Is it really possible?

I'm calling incrementDate like below:

```
<a href="" onclick="incrementDate();" />
```

Oops, I totally missed the surrounding jQuery bracket!

Comment: It's worth noting that nothing in your code or question is particular to jQuery.

Comment: I removed the jQuery tag, as your code doesn't contain any references to jQuery...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can call it. You might have to call it using the [apply](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx) which allows you to define `this` and `arguments`.

There is some docs [here](http://www.webreference.com/js/column26/apply.html) as well.

If you need some code:

```
var result = Calendar.prototype.incrementDate.apply(mycalendarObj, myArguments);
```

---

### UPDATE

OK, it seems all you need is:

```
calObject.incrementDate(1,1,1); // adds one year + one month + one day
```

Comment: thx for the references, but where does "Calendar.prototype" part come from?

Comment: From javascript language... every object has prototype, and objects are actually functions... it is confusing but it is how it is designed.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to add jQuery bracket between the code in my post. Does that affect your answer at all? I've already edited my sample code..

Comment: Put your code on jsfiddle.net and I can write a workable solution for you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NgpGg/  I've posted the code, it is big (jQuery calendar plugin...) but I put target js function in html section for u to take a look. The actually line is 685.

Comment: OK,  I will have a look and get back to you.

Comment: This does not have a UI? Where is the calendar to test?

Comment: It's been developed within salesforce platform so it is not visible from outside unless logged-in. So i cannot provide UI code. (salesforce uses evil tag <apex:...> )

Comment: No need to provide production code - all I need is one calendar on the form and one button to add dates so strip down all the production code. jquery Calendar has been supercecded by jquery datepicker so I was not able setup an example.

Comment: Ok.. I've posted html code too but only thing is importing js files are in my local so if you click on "run" button it won't show anything. But yes code is there :) hope that helps

Comment: Which URL is it at? `jsfiddle.net/NgpGg` was the old one.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NgpGg/3/ I've updated, could u please take a look again? thank you!

Comment: Great! I totally missed that such function is provided outside... thank you for all time time you spend for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can only call it on an instance of Calendar.

```
var cal = new Calendar(element, options, eventSources);
cal.incrementDate();
```

And Calendar is scoped to anonymous function you wrap the whole thing is. So that code can only appear inside that function (unless you do something to expose it).